# Auto Margin with Auto Width

Tags: html, layout, width, margin

Im trying to center a container with rows of square divs inside of it. However just trying to get it to work, Ive reduced it to a single square inside a container. It needs to auto-width but also needs to be centered. 
How can I center an container div that is using auto width? 
It only seems to center the "panel" div when its width is fixed.

```
HTML FILE  

<div class="panel">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

CSS FILE

.panel {
    position:absolute; /*This seems necessary to get the auto width to work.*/
    margin: 10px auto;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}

.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

I am eventually going to add more items inside the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your question is exactly, but you don't need to use either absolute/fixed position or left/right float to center the inner div.
To center the inner div, you can use `margin-left: 50%` minus the `margin: 30px` and your inner div will be centered. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amiregelz/urhtk/)**

Comment: Yes but once I add in more items it wouldn't be centered anymore. I'm trying to keep absolute measurements out of it where ever I can.